# all children of a node in a decision tree model has the same prediction

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml

I built a DecisionTree classifier model using spark ML 2.3. Here is a portion of the model.toDebugString

```
 Else (feature 1 > 0.25)
  If (feature 0 <= -3.3495)
   If (feature 1 <= 237.14999999999998)
    Predict: 3.0
   Else (feature 1 > 237.14999999999998)
    Predict: 3.0
  Else (feature 0 > -3.3495)
   Predict: 3.0
```

Under the top else node, all the child nodes are predicting 3, so why do we have the child nodes, why not just one node - something like this?

```
 Else (feature 1 > 0.25)
  Predict: 3.0
```

I have just set the maxdepth param.

Setting mininfogain reduces occurrences of such if/else nodes but does not remove the same. I still get if/else blocks both predicting the same value.

Is this how it is supposed to be or am I missing something?